# Formatted message using Complex Message syntax plurar

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-intl, formatjs

I try to use FormattedMesage(React intl) to using formatting API. how to create one formatted message, with the plural?
Now:

```
const outputTimeOutValues = [
        {value:'00:00:01', translationId:'passage.outputTimeOut.oneSecond'},
        {value: '00:00:03', translationId:'passage.outputTimeOut.threeSeconds'},
        {value: '00:00:05', translationId: 'passage.outputTimeOut.fiveSeconds'},
        {value: '00:00:10', translationId: 'passage.outputTimeOut.tenSeconds'},
        {value: '00:00:15', translationId: 'passage.outputTimeOut.fifteenSeconds'},
        {value: '00:00:30', translationId: 'passage.outputTimeOut.thirtySeconds'}]

    const renderMenuItems = values => values.map(({value ,translationId}) =>
        <MenuItem value={value} primaryText={<FormattedMessage id={translationId} />}/>)
```

Expected something with Message syntax

```
const renderMenuItems1 = values => values.map(({minutes, seconds}) =>
    <MenuItem value={`00:${minutes}:${seconds}`} primaryText={<FormattedMessage

        defaultMessage={'Hello {seconds}, you have {minutes, second} one {minute} other {minutes}'}
        values={{seconds, minutes}}
    />}
    />)
```

Expected text: 1second, 2second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use [injectIntl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#injectintl) to inject the intl class into your component as a prop.
You can then call `intl.formatMessage()` on the message before inserting it as the `primaryText` prop to your `MenuItem` component.